# Pareto PDF differentiation gives a negative CDF

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to calculate the CDF based on the PDF for the Pareto distribution, I've done the differentiation but I end up with a negative functionlike: $-(\frac{\lambda}{(x+\lambda)})^\alpha$

The PDF is: $\alpha\lambda^\alpha(\lambda+x)^{-\alpha-1}$

Even WolframAlpha gives me [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20a*l%5Ea(l%2Bx)%5E(-a-1))

How is it possible that the CDF is negative? isn't it supposed to be the area under the curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your parameters and the integral 
$$I(x) = \int \alpha \lambda^\alpha(\lambda+x)^{-\alpha-1} dx = -\frac{\lambda^\alpha}{(x+\lambda)^\alpha}$$ 
you get the Pareto CDF $F(x)$ as 
$$F(x) =  \int_0^x \alpha \lambda^\alpha(\lambda+t)^{-\alpha-1} dt = I(x)-I(0)= 
1 - \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{(x+\lambda)^\alpha}$$
which is valid positive CDF for $\alpha >0, \lambda > 0.$ Wolfram Alpha computes `integrate a*l^a(l+x)^(-a-1) x=0..infinity`
$$\int_0^\infty \alpha \lambda^\alpha(\lambda+t)^{-\alpha-1} dt = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you integrated. You forgot the integration constant, which by a definite integral is $1$.